# How to get the name of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

Considering the following two classes:

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : class
{
}

class PlainClass
{
}
```

I want to be able to get just the name of `GenericClass` like `"GenericClass"`. For the `PlainClass` I am able to do this using `nameof` but this does not work for the generic class:

```
var plainName = nameof(PlainClass);
var gemericName = nameof(GenericClass)//does not compile
var gemericName1 = typeof(GenericClass<>).Name; // "GenericClass`1"
```

Comment: The class' name is indeed ``GenericClass`1``. You'll need to cut off the tail if you don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really straightforward, but

```
nameof(GenericClass<object>)
```

evaluates to

```
"GenericClass"
```